# Issue with iconv() returning 500 internal server error

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv

I am trying to fire an API from Postman but it returns `500 internal server error` after execution of `iconv`. Below is the code:

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_body = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", utf8_encode($post_body));
```

Raw data passed from postman which goes in `$post_body` is below:

```
{
  "predicate":"t"
}
```

I also tried setting `header` as `key = Content-Type` and `Value = application/json`.

I am not exactly sure what is causing the issue. I searched over stack but didn't find anything that could be a solution. Can anyone suggest me something for this?

Comment: What does the PHP error log tell you?

Comment: There is no log at all. Can you tell me some way using which I can get a message in log?

Comment: Please share the full code. There must be a syntax issue either in the php or any other place like .htaccess which might be causing 500 server error.

Comment: The code I posted is the starting line of my .php file. And I get error right after these lines. May I know which other code is required? `php` is not my area so I might not be able to understand which code to share exactly.